# Suppose $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is invertible and continuous. Is the image $f(S)$ where $S$ is open neccesarily an open set?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is **bijective** and continuous. Is the image $f(S)$ where $S$ is open neccesarily an open set ?

I know the statement is true in the case of taking the preimage $f^{-1}(S)$.

Can I rewrite the above to prove that $f(S)$ is open ?

Comment: Do you mean that the inverse is defined on all of $\Bbb R^m$?

Comment: Sure, the inverse is defined everywhere.

Comment: bijective i mean

Answer (score 2):

That's a deep theorem: *Invariance of domain*. It says even more: every injective continuous mapping $\ f:U\to\mathbb R^n$ defined an open subset $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ is an open map. The proof is very difficult and belongs one way or another to Algebraic Topology. One consequence of this theorem is *Invariance of dimension:* if $\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$ then $n=m$. As for the especific question, the answer is yes.

Comment: The question should be $n$ in both cases.

Comment: Maybe I was reading the former version of the question. I've modified the last sentence.